# Can't get drush script to stop at breakpoint with Xdebug/Phpstorm

Tags: debugging, virtual-machine

I had this working on another Drupal VM, but for some reason I can't get it to work anymore.  I am trying to debug a Drush migration script and I have some breakpoints put in but it never stops at the breakpoints.  I followed the steps shown [here](http://imagexmedia.com/blog/2016/08/debugging-your-migrations-drupal-8).

Here is my Xdebug section of config.yml from Vagrant:

```
# XDebug configuration. XDebug is disabled by default for better performance.
php_xdebug_default_enable: 1
php_xdebug_coverage_enable: 1
php_xdebug_cli_enable: 1
php_xdebug_remote_enable: 1
php_xdebug_remote_connect_back: 1
php_xdebug_remote_host: xxx.xxx.xx.xx // My Vagrant IP is really here.
# Use PHPSTORM for PHPStorm, sublime.xdebug for Sublime Text.
php_xdebug_idekey: PHPSTORM
php_xdebug_max_nesting_level: 256
```

The web server debug validation shows everything is good.  I also verified that if I debug on a page that I visit from a browser, it stops at breaks points so it is for sure working.

Also, the PHP CLI does have Xdebug:

```
PHP 7.0.14-2+deb.sury.org~xenial+1 (cli) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.14-2+deb.sury.org~xenial+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2016, by Derick Rethans
```

One thing I noticed, is that if I set Phpstorm to break at first line in PHP Script, I noticed the following notice in debugger: Can't compute source position. The script 'drush.phar' isn't associated with any text file type.

Here is the Xdebug log:

```
Log opened at 2017-03-24 02:21:50
I: Connecting to configured address/port: 10.0.2.2:9000.
I: Connected to client. :-)
-> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="file:///var/www/mysite/web/drush.phar" language="PHP" xdebug:language_version="7.0.14-2+deb.sury.org~xenial+1" protocol_version="1.0" appid="12759" idekey="18466"><engine version="2.5.0"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine><author><![CDATA[Derick Rethans]]></author><url><![CDATA[http://xdebug.org]]></url><copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 2002-2016 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright></init>

<- feature_set -i 1 -n show_hidden -v 1
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="1" feature="show_hidden" success="1"></response>

<- feature_set -i 2 -n max_depth -v 1
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="2" feature="max_depth" success="1"></response>

<- feature_set -i 3 -n max_children -v 100
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="3" feature="max_children" success="1"></response>

<- status -i 4
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="status" transaction_id="4" status="starting" reason="ok"></response>

<- step_into -i 5
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="step_into" transaction_id="5" status="break" reason="ok"><xdebug:message filename="file:///var/www/mysite/web/drush.phar" lineno="8"></xdebug:message></response>

<- breakpoint_set -i 6 -t line -f file:///var/www/mysite/web/modules/contrib/migrate_tools/migrate_tools.drush.inc -n 226
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="6" id="127590001"></response>

<- breakpoint_set -i 7 -t line -f file:///var/www/mysite/web/core/modules/field/src/Plugin/migrate/source/d6/FieldInstance.php -n 22
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="7" id="127590002"></response>

<- breakpoint_set -i 8 -t line -f file:///var/www/mysite/web/core/modules/field/src/Plugin/migrate/source/d6/FieldInstance.php -n 56
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="8" id="127590003"></response>

<- breakpoint_set -i 9 -t line -f file:///var/www/mysite/web/core/modules/field/src/Plugin/migrate/source/d6/FieldInstance.php -n 37
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="9" id="127590004"></response>

<- stack_get -i 10
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="stack_get" transaction_id="10"><stack where="{main}" level="0" type="file" filename="file:///var/www/mysite/web/drush.phar" lineno="8"></stack></response>

<- run -i 11
Log opened at 2017-03-24 02:21:51
I: Connecting to configured address/port: xxx.xxx.xx.xx:9000.
W: Creating socket for 'xxx.xxx.xx.xx:9000', poll success, but error: Operation now in progress (29).
E: Could not connect to client. :-(
Log closed at 2017-03-24 02:21:51
```

Any ideas on what I can try to get it to work?

**Update - Things I have tried**

- Destroy vagrant machine and start over
- Different combination of
  Xdebug settings in config.yml (Set to how it comes by default,
  removing remote_host, adding localhost, etc..)
- Changing port to 9001
  (both PHPStorm and Vagrant)

Answer (score 5):

I just had this problem. It happened because I was using drush launcher (https://github.com/drush-ops/drush-launcher). This tool allows to type "drush" in your Drupal directory, instead of "./vendor/bin/drush", but it seems to confuse xdebug. Using "./vendor/bin/drush" fixed the problem.

Comment: This put me on the right path, I also had to set an environment variable in the container: `export PHP_IDE_CONFIG="serverName=MyServer"` where MyServer is the name of the server in Preferences / Languages & Frameworks / PHP / Servers where you do your path mapping

Comment: Specifically, drush-launcher unloads xdebug for speed purposes. See https://github.com/drush-ops/drush-launcher#xdebug-compatibility for an env variable which disables this behavior. Or just use vendor/bin/drush as this answer suggests.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this can help: [Debugging PHP CLI scripts with PhpStorm](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Debugging+PHP+CLI+scripts+with+PhpStorm)