# Is there an easy way to call a migration from a controller for debugging purposes

Tags: 8, migrations

I am trying to debug a migration and having issues getting xdebug to work with drush as I described in this [issue](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/232208/cant-get-drush-script-to-stop-at-breakpoint-with-xdebug-phpstorm).  Would there be an easy way for me to call a migration from a controller (I am able to text xdebug from browser)?

For example, I would like to debug this:

```
drush mi upgrade_d6_field_instance
```

I was thinking to create a custom module that adds a controller that I can call the migration from the browser. The only option I cant think of is to recreate a lot of the functions from migrate_tools in the controller but I feel like there has to be an easier way.

Comment: This module executes a migrate via a (GUI) batch: https://www.drupal.org/project/usebb2drupal. May be this can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the code isn't that hard to recreate from migration_tools. Here is my controller class:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\custom_migration\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use Drupal\migrate\MigrateExecutable;
use Drupal\migrate\MigrateMessage;

class MigrateController extends ControllerBase {

  public function process() {

    $migration = \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.config_entity_migration')->createInstance('upgrade_d6_field_instance');
    $executable = new MigrateExecutable($migration, new MigrateMessage());
    $executable->import();


    return ['#markup' => 'Migrate Debugging'];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found debugging drush commands in PhpStorm pretty easy - at least when not running them in a VM (still struggling with setting that up). One key point is that in Preferences->Languages & Frameworks->PHP->Debug, be sure to bump up "Max simultaneous connections" (I have mine set to 10), a value of 1 will *not* work with drush.